# Summernote custom button with dialog

Tags: summernote

I want to add a custom button to the Summernote toolbar that opens up a dialog that has a textbox for a URL and several checkboxes for settings. I then want to use the info from the dialog to scrape web pages and do processing on the content.  The ultimate goal is to place the scraped content into the editor starting where the cursor is. I've searched and found some code on creating a custom button, but not any solid examples of implementing a dialog.  I went through the summernote.js code to see how the Insert Image dialog works and that left me really confused. The test code I've got so far is in the code block, below.  Thanks in advance to anyone who can help get me sorted out.

```
                var showModalDialog = function(){
                    alert("Not Implemented");
                };
                
                
                var AddWiki = function(context) {
                    var ui = $.summernote.ui;
                    var button = ui.button({
                        contents: '<i class="fa fa-plus"/> Add Wiki',
                        tooltip: "Set a New Wiki",
                        class: "btn-primary",
                        click: function() {
                          showModalDialog();
                        }
                    });
                    return button.render();
                };              
                
                
                $(".tw-summernote-instance textarea").summernote({
                      airMode: false,
                      dialogsInBody: false,
                      toolbar: [["mybutton", ["customButton"]]],
                      buttons: {
                        customButton: AddWiki
                      },
                      callbacks: {
                        onInit: function(e) {
                          var o = e.toolbar[0];
                          jQuery(o)
                            .find("button:first")
                            .addClass("btn-primary");
                        }
                      }
                    });
```

Answer (score 1):

I found a good, simple example of what I wanted to do.  Here's the code:

```
(function(factory) {
  /* global define */
  if (typeof define === 'function' && define.amd) {
    // AMD. Register as an anonymous module.
    define(['jquery'], factory);
  } else if (typeof module === 'object' && module.exports) {
    // Node/CommonJS
    module.exports = factory(require('jquery'));
  } else {
    // Browser globals
    factory(window.jQuery);
  }
}(function($) {
  $.extend($.summernote.plugins, {

    'synonym': function(context) {
      var self = this;
      var ui = $.summernote.ui;

      var $editor = context.layoutInfo.editor;
      var options = context.options;

      context.memo('button.synonym', function() {
        return ui.button({
          contents: '<i class="fa fa-snowflake-o">',
          tooltip: 'Create Synonym',
          click: context.createInvokeHandler('synonym.showDialog')
        }).render();
      });

      self.initialize = function() {
        var $container = options.dialogsInBody ? $(document.body) : $editor;

        var body = '<div class="form-group">' +
          '<label>Add Synonyms (comma - , - seperated</label>' +
          '<input id="input-synonym" class="form-control" type="text" placeholder="Insert your synonym" />'
        '</div>'
        var footer = '<button href="#" class="btn btn-primary ext-synonym-btn">OK</button>';

        self.$dialog = ui.dialog({
          title: 'Create Synonym',
          fade: options.dialogsFade,
          body: body,
          footer: footer
        }).render().appendTo($container);
      };

      // You should remove elements on `initialize`.
      self.destroy = function() {
        self.$dialog.remove();
        self.$dialog = null;
      };

      self.showDialog = function() {
        self
          .openDialog()
          .then(function(data) {
            ui.hideDialog(self.$dialog);
            context.invoke('editor.restoreRange');
            self.insertToEditor(data);

            console.log("dialog returned: ", data)
          })
          .fail(function() {
            context.invoke('editor.restoreRange');
          });
      };

      self.openDialog = function() {
        return $.Deferred(function(deferred) {
          var $dialogBtn = self.$dialog.find('.ext-synonym-btn');
          var $synonymInput = self.$dialog.find('#input-synonym')[0];

          ui.onDialogShown(self.$dialog, function() {
            context.triggerEvent('dialog.shown');

            $dialogBtn
              .click(function(event) {
                event.preventDefault();

                deferred.resolve({
                  synonym: $synonymInput.value
                });
              });
          });

          ui.onDialogHidden(self.$dialog, function() {
            $dialogBtn.off('click');

            if (deferred.state() === 'pending') {
              deferred.reject();
            }
          });

          ui.showDialog(self.$dialog);
        });
      };

      this.insertToEditor = function(data) {
        console.log("synonym: " + data.synonym)

        var dataArr = data.synonym.split(',');
        var restArr = dataArr.slice(1);

        var $elem = $('<span>', {
          'data-function': "addSynonym",
          'data-options': '[' + restArr.join(',').trim() + ']',
          'html': $('<span>', {
            'text': dataArr[0],
            'css': {
              backgroundColor: 'yellow'
            }
          })
        });

        context.invoke('editor.insertNode', $elem[0]);
      };
    }
  });
}));
```